# Controller does not work

Tags: magento2, controllers, factory

this is my controller

```
<?php

namespace Prevaj\Orderswatches\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {


    protected $_pageFactory;

    /**
     * Undocumented function
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory
     * @return void
     */
    public function __contruct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory
    ){
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute(){
        return $this->_pageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

this is the error im facing

Error: Call to a member function create() on null in /var/www/island.importers/app/code/Prevaj/Orderswatches/Controller/Index/Index.php:26 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/island.importers/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Prevaj\Orderswatches\Controller\Index\Index->execute() #1 /var/www/island.importers/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Prevaj\Orderswatches\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent() #2 /var/www/island.importers/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Plugin/ActionFlagNoDispatchPlugin.php(51): Prevaj\Orderswatches\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}() #3 /var/www/island.importers/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Plugin\ActionFlagNoDispatchPlugin->aroundExecute() #4 /var/www/island.importers/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Prevaj\Orderswatches\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}() #5 /var/www/island.importers/generated/code/Prevaj/Orderswatches/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(39):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You omitted a letter in the function name:

```
public function __contruct(
```

Correct would be:

```
public function __construct(
```

Comment: This is a silly mistake i feel ashamed. Ty for helping

Comment: No problem, mate :D Anyway